# SignInAnonymously() doesn't return full user information, it returns "FirebaseUser(Instance of 'PlatformUser')"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Instead of returning full user info like UserId and stuff, I receive FirebaseUser(Instance of 'PlatformUser'). What seems to go wrong?

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign in with email & password

  // register with email & password

  // sign out

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. It returns a `FirebaseUser` instance which _does_ contain all that data. The `FirebaseUser` class has [methods to read all the info you mentioned](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser), like `getEmail`, `getUid`, etc. - What is missing?

Comment: Can you show how you call `signInAnon`? It's typically easiest to help if your `print` a value in your code that shows the unexpected value, and then include *that* code and its output in your question.